# How do I insert a background image from my disk into restructuredtext

Tags: restructuredtext, rst2pdf

Including an image is easy-enough...

```
.. image:: /home/mpenning/ciscoconfparse_logo_bw_01.png
   :align: center
```

However, I want to use it as a background image... I tried this html with a z-index:

```
.. raw:: html

   <div>
      <style>
         body {
           background-color: white;
           background-image: url('/home/mpenning/ciscoconfparse_logo_bw_01.png');
           z-index: -1;
         }
      </style>
   </div>
```

However, that does not render the background image with [`rst2pdf`](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf).

How do I render a background image with restructured-text as a PDF (using [`rst2pdf`](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [explicit solution](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf/issues/1183) that worked...

```
.. raw:: pdf

   PageBreak background=/path/to/backgroundimage
```

Total solution... FYI, `center` is the default...

```
Insert Presentation Title with normal image

.. image:: /home/mpenning/ciscoconfparse_logo_bw_01.png
   :align: center

.. raw:: pdf

    PageBreak background=/home/mpenning/ciscoconfparse_logo_bw_01.png fit-background-mode=center

- Bullet 1 (with background image)
- Bullet 2 (with background image)
- Bullet 3 (with background image)
```